# C++ BOOST: windows shared memory get_size() returns zero

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

The below is from the official BOOST docs.
Why do I always get size of zero when calling `region.get_size()` ? What am I doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  //Create a native windows shared memory object.
  windows_shared_memory shm (create_only, "MySharedMemory", read_write, 1000);

  //Map the whole shared memory in this process
  mapped_region region(shm, read_write);
  cout << "SIZE IS " << region.get_size() << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I got the answer: 
From boost docs:

> Native windows shared memory has also
>   another limitation: a process can open
>   and map the whole shared memory
>   created by another process but it
>   can't know which is the size of that
>   memory. This limitation is imposed by
>   the Windows API so the user must
>   somehow transmit the size of the
>   segment to processes opening the
>   segment.

Answer (score 1):

In the [boost::interprocess documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/boost/interprocess/mapped_region.html#id812790-bb) for the `mapped_region` constructor you're using it says:

> Creates a mapping region of the mapped
>   memory "mapping", starting in offset
>   "offset", ***and the mapping's size will
>   be "size"***. The mapping can be opened
>   for read-only "read_only" or
>   read-write "read_write.

So provide a non-zero size and everything will work as expected:
`mapped_region region(shm, read_write, 0, 1000);`

Comment: Not according to the docs. There should not be a call to mapped_region with size in windows. See my answer above